# Constructor object model JS

Tags: javascript, api, object-model

So I'm all new to JavaScript and for a school assignment we were asked to use the NY-Times API to create a web-project. My teacher wants me to rewrite this code, using a constructor object model. So my question is, how can this be done?

```
 $.getJSON('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/events/v2/listings.json', 
            {'api-key': "2cb941103998461990415c7e7fafb8c7",  'filters': "-movies"
            },
            function(data) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) { 
      var event= data.results[i];


var nameEvent= event.event_name; 
var Category3= event.category
var descriptionWeb= event.web_description
var Borough3 = event.borough;
var timeAndTime = event.date_time_description;

var eventPost = {
    eventName: nameEvent,
    category: Category3,
    description: descriptionWeb,
    borough: Borough3,
    time: timeAndTime
    };

var eventHTML= $( '<event>' 
+ '  <h2>'+ nameEvent  + '</h2>'
+ '  <h3>'+ Category3 + '</h3>' 
+ '  <p>' + descriptionWeb + '</p>' 
+ '  <p>' + Borough3 + '</p>' 
+ '  <p>' + timeAndTime + '</p>'
+ '</event>' );

var events= $('#EVENTS'); 
events.append(eventHTML);
}
} 
);
```

Comment: Maybe look into this MDN tutorial about Object oriented programming in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have created object so if you want a new object you need to write their properties each time . now this function(constructor) will take care of that . and you can create object as many as possible.

```js
function model(a,b,c,d,e) {
  this.eventName = a;
  this.category = b;
  this.description = c;
  this.borough = d;
  this.time = e;
}


var eventPost =new model (nameEvent,Category3,descriptionWeb,Borough3,timeAndTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! what piece of code does this replace?

Comment: @JulieBang add function model into your code . and eventpost object would be 2nd line

Comment: @Mahi did you try to run the snippet? It has syntax error. Also, it is good to explain the code.